# Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie" with ajax call Rest server

Tags: rest, jquery, drupal, cookies, cordova

Im busy building a Phonegap app that connects with my Drupal rest server (Module: Services).
My Drupal website (PHP) has the code: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

When I'm trying to connect to my Rest server with the following code: http://pastebin.com/xfygQexn I'm getting the following console message: Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"

Code: http://pastebin.com/FNGgPQKv
Error: Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Many thanks.

Im needing the token and the session for a logout call.

Comment: I am not familiar with this, but have you seen DrupalGap? https://drupal.org/project/drupalgap

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to set cookies for separate ajax call but this is not allowed by [XMLHttpRequest specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method). Instead, you can set a cookie to the current page and browser will put it in your ajax request if domain/path matches, i.e. by using [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { path: '/' });
```