# dart:html HttpRequest Refused to set unsafe header & No Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: dart, httprequest, dart-io

I want to put the value to the Http Header(etc Cookie, User-Agent ...)

When setting "Cookie" & "User-Agent" values in Http Header the following error message is displayed.

How do can I put a value in Http Header?

Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie" 
Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"
XMLHttpRequest cannot load serverip. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'datium server' is therefore not allowed access.

```dart
import "dart:html";
import "dart:convert";


final ButtonElement loginButton = querySelector("#login");

void main() {

  loginButton.onClick.listen((e) {

    requstTest();

  });

}

void requstTest(){

  var request = new HttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', 'serverurl');

  request.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID : cdsfasdfA49596CBD1949");

  request.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "test");

  request.onLoad.listen((event) => print('Request complete ${event.target.reponseText}'));

  request.send();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting cookies for individual HtmlRequest calls seems not to be allowed on the client

[Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie" with ajax call Rest server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005391/refused-to-set-unsafe-header-cookie-with-ajax-call-rest-server)

You can set cookies on the document

```dart
document.cookie = "JSESSIONID=caölsdjf";
```

There are libraries available to make this easier: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cookie

Faking the user-agent is generally not allowed in browsers as far as I know.

This spec contains the list of headers which browsers must not allow:

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader