# Refuse to set Cookie Error while setting header in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am trying to call a webservice using `$http` in AngularJS. I have defined a `$httpProvider` for my module that adds certain headers to every HTTP request made.

All the headers that I set currently are getting reflected in the request that is sent (when checked in the Network tab of Google Chrome). However the following line does not set the header for the cookie value

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Cookie'] = "test123";
```

When I use this line, I get the error in my console as

```
 "Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"
```

And when I check the request headers in the network tab, the value for Cookie is something like

```
 Cookie:csrftoken=tQATyTRP64PqNjvb9e2znhExGRtcJH6e; DoNotShowFTU=true;
      lastMangerHost=http%3A//localhost%3A8089; showRightRail=true
```

So, why isn't the browser accepting the cookie that I have set. Can someone help me resolve this. I basically want to pass the cookie value in the header of my HTTP POST request.

This is my complete code.

```
  var testCookieApp = angular.module('sampleCookieApp', []).run(function($http){

 $http.defaults.headers.common['tenant_id'] = "123";
 $http.defaults.headers.common['cas_filter_user'] = "parth";  
 $http.defaults.headers.common['user_desc'] = 'null';
 $http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
 //set cookies with key name 'Cookie' gives error in browser
 $http.defaults.headers.common['Cookie'] = "test123";
 $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = true;
 $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
 $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*';
 $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = '*';
 $http.defaults.headers.common['crossDomain'] = true;

 });


 testCookieApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

   $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

 }]);



testCookieApp.controller("TestCookieController", function ($scope, $http,$q) {

$scope.authenticateUser = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/RestEasyExample/rest/getData',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'       
        }
    }).success(function (data) { 
        alert("success");
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function (data) {
        alert("error");
        deferred.reject('There was an error while making request');       
    });
  };

 });
```

Currently, I get "success" page when the webservice runs but the cookie is not set in the header.

Comment: You may try to set the cookie on page instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21939238/3563439

Comment: @KostyaShkryob: Your link was helpful. I have another question. If I change my key name from 'Cookie' to something like 'Authorization' then the value is sent. So that means I need to change my server side logic right?

Comment: You can set cookie value with document.cookie or with ngCookies module and it will be sent to server with each HTTP request.